# Mean distance from one city to others by a mutual ID

Tags: r, geospatial, distance

I don't understand spatial.data at all. I have been studying but I'm missing something.

**What I have:** data.frame `enterprises` with the columns: id, parent_subsidiary, city_cod.

**What I need:** the mean and the max distance from the parent's city to the subsidiary cities.

Ex:

```
    id         |     mean_dist     | max_dist
 1111          |         25km      |     50km    
 232           |        110km      |    180km  
 333           |          0km      |      0km
```

**What I did** :

```
library("tidyverse")
library("sf")
# library("brazilmaps")   not working anymore
library("geobr")


parent <- enterprises %>% filter(parent_subsidiary==1) 
subsidiary <- enterprises %>% filter(parent_subsidiary==2) 

# Cities - polygons 
m_city_br <- read_municipality(code_muni="all", year=2019)

# or shp_city<- st_read("/BR_Municipios_2019.shp")

# data.frame with the column geom
map_parent  <- left_join(parent, m_city_br, by=c("city_cod"="code_muni"))
map_subsidiary <- left_join(subsidiary, m_city_br, by=c("city_cod"="code_muni"))



st_distance(map_parent$geom[1],map_subsidiary$geom[2]) %>% units::set_units(km)
# it took a long time and the result is different from google.maps
# is it ok?!


# To do by ID -- I also stucked here

distance_p_s <- data.frame(id=as.numeric(),subsidiar=as.numeric(),mean_dist=as.numeric(),max_dist=as.numeric())

id_v <- as.vector(parent$id)



for (i in 1:length(id_v)){
  
 
  test_p <- map_parent %>% filter(id==id_v[i])  
  test_s <- map_subsidiary %>% filter(id==id_v[i])
  total <- 0
  value <- 0
  max <- 0
  l <- 0
  
  l <- nrow(test_s)

      for (j in 1:l){

         value <- as.numeric(round(st_distance(test_p$geom[1],test_s$geom[j]) %>% units::set_units(km),2))
          
         total <- total + value
         ifelse(value>max,max<-value,NA)
      }
  

  mean_dist <- total/l
  done <- data.frame(id=id[i],subsidiary=l,mean_dist=round(mean_dist,2),max_dist=max)
  distance_p_s <- rbind(distance_p_s,done)
  
  rm(done)
  
}
}
```

Is it right?
Can I calculate  the centroid of the cities and than calculate the distance?

I realize that the distance from code_muni==4111407 to code_muni==4110102, the distance is 0, but is another city (Imbituva, PR,Brasil - Ivaí, PR,Brasil). Why?

**Data example**: `structure(list(id = c("1111", "1111", "1111",  "1111", "232", "232", "232", "232", "3123",  "3123", "4455", "4455", "686", "333", "333",  "14112", "14112", "14112", "3633", "3633"), parent_subsidiary = c("1","2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2",  "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2"), city_cod = c(4305801L,4202404L, 4314803L, 4314902L, 4318705L, 1303403L, 4304507L, 4314100L,  2408102L, 3144409L, 5208707L, 4205407L, 5210000L, 3203908L, 3518800L,  3118601L, 4217303L, 3118601L, 5003702L, 5205109L)), row.names = c(NA,  20L), class = "data.frame")`

PS: this is Brazilian cities
https://github.com/ipeaGIT/geobr/tree/master/r-package

Comment: Hi.  Need to see some or all of the df, enterprise, before answering your question.

Comment: part of my data is already here. I just changed the ID.

Comment: If you be still looking for some answers to this aging question, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like that:

```
distance_p_s <- data.frame(id=as.character(),
                            qtd_subsidiary=as.numeric(),
                            dist_min=as.numeric(),
                            dist_media=as.numeric(),
                            dist_max=as.numeric())

id <- as.vector(mparentid$id)

for (i in 1:length(id)){
  
  eval(parse(text=paste0("
                         print('Filtering id: ",id[i]," (",i," of ",length(id),")')
                         ")))
  teste_m <- mparentid %>% filter(id==id[i]) %>% st_as_sf()
  teste_f <- msubsidiaryid %>% filter(id==id[i]) %>% st_as_sf()
  
  teste_f <- st_centroid(teste_f)
  teste_m <- st_centroid(teste_m)
  
  teste_f = st_transform(teste_f, 4674)
  teste_m = st_transform(teste_m, 4674)
  
  total <- 0
  value <- 0
  min <- 0
  max <- 0
  l <- 0
  
  l <- nrow(teste_f)
  
  for (j in 1:l){
    
    eval(parse(text=paste0("
                         print('Tratando id: ",id[i]," (",i," de ",length(id),"), subsidiary: ",j," de ",l,"')
                         ")))
    
    value <- as.numeric(round(st_distance(teste_m$geom[1],teste_f$geom[j]) %>% units::set_units(km),2))
    
    total <- total + value
    ifelse(value>max,max<-value,NA)
    if(j==1){
      min<-value
    } else { 
      ifelse(value<min,min<-value,NA)}
  }
  
  
  dist_med <- total/l
  done <- data.frame(id=id[i],qtd_subsidiary=l,dist_min=min,dist_media=round(dist_med,2),dist_max=max)
  distance_p_s <- rbind(distance_p_s,done)
  
  eval(parse(text=paste0("
                         print('Concluido id: ",id[i]," (",i," de ",length(id),"), subsidiary: ",j," de ",l,"')
                         ")))
  
  rm(done)
  
}
```

Probably this is not the best way, but it solved my problem for now.

Answer (score 1):

Great problem.  I looked at it for a little while.  Then I came back and looked some more after thinking about it.  The mean was not calculated. Only the distances were determined from each parent to its subsidiaries.

The data was binded  - the cities data and the data frame data.  Then the new df was mutated to add the centroid data for each   point on the surface.

The df was split by id and resulted in a list of 8 df's.  Each df  contained separate parent with related subsidiaries. (1:4, 1:3, 1:4, 1:2, .... )

A loop with a function cleaned up the 8 df's, and calculated the distance from each parent to each subsidiary.

I checked the distance of the first df in the list against values for distances from a website.  The distances of df1 were nearly identical to the website.

The output is shown at [[link]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGDpZ.png)

Comment: Sorry! I've been busy later. Yes, I already solve it with a loop! I will put my answer here! Thank you so much for your attention!